# Vagrantfile not respecting nginx version using Chef for provisioning

Tags: nginx, chef-infra, vagrant

Getting started with using Vagrant for some Rails development. Going one step at a time, so I'm first trying to install nginx via a Chef recipe in the vagrant file. However, while I set the nginx version in the `Vagrantfile` to `1.20.0`, Vagrant does not seem to recognize it and keeps installing version `1.1.19`.

I'm going to go through all my steps to make sure I'm not missing anything.

I've got a directory structure of:

```
--vagrant_boxes
  --cookbooks
  --vagrant_box1
```

I downloaded the nginx cookbook from opscode via knife.

```
knife cookbook site install nginx
```

This installed nginx and its dependencies into my `cookbooks` directory.

I then created a new box in `vagrant_box1`

```
vagrant init precise64
```

and edited the Vagrant file to read

```
config.vm.provision :chef_solo do |chef|
  chef.cookbooks_path = "../cookbooks"
  chef.add_recipe "nginx"
  chef.json = { :nginx => { :version => "1.2.0" } }
end
```

I ran `vagrant up`, and then `vagrant ssh`.

And in the Vagrant box, `nginx -v` gave me `nginx version: nginx/1.1.19`. Which is not what I want. I want to understand Vagrant and chef, so any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC the version attribute only applies to the nginx::source recipe.  So instead of:

```
chef.add_recipe "nginx"
```

try:

```
chef.add_recipe "nginx::source"
```

Then the correct version should be installed

Comment: Could not install nginx with ::default recipe, but could with ::source. Thank you @turtlebender